# How do I format a url to return only a specific element from the JSON object?

Tags: json

I'm trying to get only the BTC_BTS data from this endpoint:

https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker

How can I format the url to only return that data and not the rest of the ticker pairs?

Comment: Please show people what you have tried and did not work, possibly with some code example, so that they can better understand your problem and try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a get request to that endpoint and go through the response depending on your language. For JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker",
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.BTC_BTS);
  });
```

Comment: ok, would I be able to simply format the url in a way that does this for me?, like: https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker&BTC_BTS or something like that? Or is that just not the standard way to do this?

Comment: looks like from their documentation: https://docs.poloniex.com/#public-http-api-methods that is included in the public http api methods (there are 7), the closest api I can see for that purpose is returnChartData, with an example given https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_BTS&start=1571366212&end=1571279812&period=300 where start and end are in epoch time so, you can use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert, otherwise you would have to manipulate their api and make your own endpoint to suit your use case.

Comment: @CuongNguyen This method is work is app script, but what about if the BTC_BTS Dynamic is change for Avery time people call another coin, I try by this code `var fullsymbol = 'USDT_BTC'; const price = jsonResponce.fullsymbol` but not working. How can I fix it?